# Passing arguments to nagios plugin

Tags: nagios

I've installed my first plugin on a Nagios server, but am having trouble getting the arguments right. I've tried some things with $ARG1$ but am essentially just flopping around.

One complication, perhaps: this plugin is supposed to run on the nagios server itself; no npre call to a remote box.

The plugin is a shell script that makes a curl call against a remote box under the hood. Typical command line use with flags would read:

```
my_shell_script.sh -H my.server.of.interest -P 9000 -I ./tmp/settings_file -timeout 80
```

(yes, it has its own '-H' flag, unrelated to nagios' hostname flag.)

Here's the skeleton I have right now. Nagios appears to think all my flags are one giant one.

```
define command {
   command_name    my_command
   command_line    $USER1$/my_shell_script.sh $ARG1$
}

define service {
   use                  generic-service;
   host_name            {{what do I put here?  This is supposed to run on the nagios box itself. My shell script is installed on it.}};
   service_description      some description
   check_command         my_command!{{what goes here?}}
}
```

The above is a little stripped down for readability, but that's the gist of it. It's the hostname and arguments and bits in the 'what do I put here' that are giving me trouble. I could use a nudge, and thanks for the suggestions.

[Edit] it seems the intent of my post has been misunderstood, through my own language.

When I say I 'am essentially flopping around', that comes after several attempts at using the $ARG$ macros and rearranging things in a number of ways and realizing what I was trying simply wasn't working.  I intentionally put up a simplified version of my plugin code in an attempt to get a point in the right direction.

Comment: Instead of random shots, just read the docs. If something is still unclear after that, ask questions.

Comment: I've been looking over the nagios documentation while doing this...do you have any good links from their documentation on command line arguments I can review?

Comment: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/macros.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the service definition you put the host_name of the host where the service is running that you want to check.

The check_command definition `my_command!whatever` will pass `whatever` to the command definition as $ARG1$. Add more `!more` for $ARG2$, etc.

You need to pass the needed parameters to `my_shell_script.sh` in the command definition. You have access to things like $HOSTNAME$ and $HOSTADDRESS$; the command you define in the `define command` section will be run locally on the nagios server; for things like nrpe there's a command definition that connects to the nrpe server... hence also then the command is run locally!

Start [here](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/toc.html) for nagios documentation, e.g. "The Basics" and "Standard Macros in Nagios".

Answer (score 1):

To Register and use custom plugin with parameter use following example

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=$1
if curl -s --head $URL | grep "200 OK" > /dev/null
then echo "Ok - $URL is up!"
exit 0
else echo "CRITICAL - $URL is down!"
exit 2
fi
```

Give Required permission and ownership same permission as built-in plugin

To test plugin individually

```
./check_web_url <<WEBSITE_URL>>
```

add defination in commands.cfg

```
define command {
       command_name check_web_url
       command_line $USER1$/check_web_url $ARG1$
}
```

Add check_web_url in cfg file

```
define service{
        use                             local-service
        host_name                       <specify-hostname>
        service_description             Check url 
        check_command                   check_web_url!http://website_url_will_here
        check_interval                  1
}
```